# AsyncHttpClient does not use provided proxy data

Tags: java, android-async-http, asynchttpclient

I've written a query tool which at it's heart uses this block to gather info from an external url:

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig proxiedCF = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setUserAgent(pickUserAgent()).build();
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(proxiedCF);
Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url).setProxyServer(new ProxyServer.Builder(pickProxyServer(), 80)).execute();
```

It works fine. However it works even when an invalid proxy is provided, which is a bit suspicious and I feel my elaborate proxy configuration is not used at all.

I stumbled upon this by having pickProxyServer() return a String "1.1.1.1", which is obviously not a valid web proxy.

I use SLF4J for logging and it looks pretty normal:

```
20:31:47.454 [AsyncHttpClient-7-1] DEBUG o.a.n.channel.NettyConnectListener - Using new Channel '[id: 0x03359938, L:/10.0.0.101:59775 - R:/1.1.1.1:80]' for 'GET' to '[[url removed by me]]'
20:31:47.586 [AsyncHttpClient-7-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.handler.HttpHandler - 

Request DefaultFullHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: EmptyByteBufBE)
GET [[url removed by me]] HTTP/1.1
Host: [[url removed by me]]
Accept: */*
User-Agent: burning_dandelion

Response DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 18:31:49 GMT
Expires: Fri, 13 Oct 2017 18:31:49 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy!"
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2017-10-13-18; expires=Fri, 20-Oct-2017 18:31:49 GMT; path=/; domain=[[url removed by me]]
Set-Cookie: NID=114=qiVBv02cmXYHh2RfLQbhBfESWIoaGlf3d2jlSbAdQ8yWPDsCpOeK9aYbvfq0HWsER68W1oE53jiriM_fivTc1bJi1F2sfCi0wMptKI-9U3ueVKITtFvYYZx2T0rJf1kQ; expires=Sat, 14-Apr-2018 18:31:49 GMT; path=/; domain=[[url removed by me]]; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

20:31:47.587 [AsyncHttpClient-7-1] DEBUG o.a.netty.channel.ChannelManager - Adding key: ProxyPartitionKey(proxyHost=1.1.1.1, proxyPort=80, secured=false, targetHostBaseUrl=[[url removed by me]]:80 for channel [id: 0x03359938, L:/10.0.0.101:59775 - R:/1.1.1.1:80]
```

Can someone point me towards my error? Obviously, I want an I/O exception or any kind of notice when an invalid proxy is called upon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's the middle of the night but I found something. When the port is anything but :80, the proxy is correctly used. This does the trick for me.